# web audio - merge 3 audiostreams into 1

Tags: web-audio-api

Pretty confident that it should be possible.

Currently i can only get the stream from one:

```
let mediaElement = document.createElement("img");
mediaElement.className = "fileMedia";
mediaElement.style.maxWidth = "280px";
mediaElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
mediaElement.controls = true;
mediaElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedLocalMedia); // a file from type="file" input

  let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  // create placeholder stream from our AudioContext
  let dest = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  this.audioStream[pluginHandleIndex] = dest.stream;

  // connect our video element's output to the stream
  let sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElement);

  // if (pluginHandleIndex > 0) {
  //   let testvideo = document.getElementById("testvideo");
  //   let sourceNodeTwo = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(testvideo);
  //   sourceNodeTwo.connect(dest);
  // }
  sourceNode.connect(dest);
  sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

How can i add more audio streams to `this.audioStream[pluginHandleIndex]`( `audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination()` ) ?

If you see commented lines

```
// if (pluginHandleIndex > 0) {
  //   let testvideo = document.getElementById("testvideo");
  //   let sourceNodeTwo = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(testvideo);
  //   sourceNodeTwo.connect(dest);
  // }
```

I try to attach tome like the first time, but this doesn't seem to work :/

Thanks!

Comment: What behavior are you trying to get?  Mixing the sources together, or stacking them as different channels?

Comment: What is the difference between those two? All i want is to merge the audio streams into 1 so i can stream it trought wbertc to other listeners. Right now i have 3 seperate audiostrems which is bad for resources.